# Use root-account once, to allow change of CPU-governor without root in future

Tags: android, root, scaling, cpu-speed

I'm the developer of a root-app with hundred thousand of users.

Trying to avoid to ask users for root all the time they are doing a root-requiring command, I'm always searching for tricks around - so my users are as less disturbed as possible by dialogs, as it's mostly running as a background-service.

This time, I would like to allow to change the CPU-governor frequently depending on current circumstances, but if possible without always using root-access.

I already tried to `chmod 777 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` with root, but an `echo interactive > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`  without root still produces "access defnied".

It seems to be possible in general under unix-environments, so maybe someone has a hint like this can be done but for Android?

http://scape.cs.vt.edu/~mjeg/blog/2011/05/07/non-root-change-cpufreq

Comment: **Luckily**, Android is a **secure** system. Otherwise **virus** writers would have an easy play. You'd bBetter ask your user to **explicitly** root their system.

Comment: Hey Frank, oh yes you are fully right about this. But, my users already own a rooted device so that's not the problem. My "problem" is more that I don't want to use root all and every time if there isn't a workaround, like adjusting eg. simply the chmod via root and then don't need to use root anymore :)